# Screaming frog sees a link to a page which is not there but shows

Tags: php, wordpress, selector

This is the selector script I believe below so what should happen is as you select a product then you select if its your an individual or couple or family then you click show me and it takes you to the correct link

```
<div class="finder__selector">
    <?php /* Set first option as the default option */ ?>
    <?php $count = 1; while ( have_rows('links') ) : the_row(); ?>

        <?php $link_url = get_sub_field('link_url'); ?>

        <?php if($product_name): ?>
            <?php //echo $product_name; ?>
            <?php //echo $link_url; ?>

            <?php if(strpos($link_url, $product_name) !== false): ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link_url; ?>" class="finder__placeholder"><?php the_sub_field('link_title'); ?><i class="down-arrow"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php if($count == 1) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link_url; ?>" class="finder__placeholder"><?php the_sub_field('link_title'); ?><i class="down-arrow"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php $count++; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>


    <div class="finder__options">
        <?php $count = 1; ?>

        <?php while ( have_rows('links') ) : the_row(); ?>
            <?php $link_url_select = get_sub_field('link_url'); ?>
            <?php $link_title_select = get_sub_field('link_title'); ?>

            <?php if($product_name): ?>
                <?php if(strpos($link_url_select, $product_name) !== false): ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link_url_select; ?>" class="finder__option is-active"><?php echo $link_title_select; ?><i class="down-arrow"></i></a>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $link_url_select; ?>" class="finder__option"><?php echo $link_title_select; ?><i class="down-arrow"></i></a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php else: ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $link_url_select; ?>" class="finder__option<?php if($count == 1) { echo ' is-active'; } ?>"><?php echo $link_title_select; ?><i class="down-arrow"></i></a>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php $count++; ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
```

So the above works but whats its actually showing on view source and what creaming frog is 404 is

```
href="&audience=couples" class=finder__option>
my partner and I <i
class=down-arrow></i>
</a>
<a
href="&audience=families" class=finder__option>
my family <i
class=down-arrow></i>
```